Why some instructions are CMODX(Concurrent modification and execution) safe while others not on ARM?
The Arm Architecture Spec defines a set of instructions which is CMODX
safe. For other instructions, the effect of CMODX is UNPREDICTABLE.

The Arm architecture limits the set of instructions that can be  executed by one thread of execution as they are being modified by  another thread of execution without requiring explicit synchronization.
Concurrent modification and execution of instructions can lead to the resulting instruction performing any behavior that can be achieved by executing any sequence of instructions that can be executed from the same Exception level, except where each of the instruction before modification and the instruction after modification is one of a B, B.cond, BL, BRK, CBNZ, CBZ, HVC, ISB, NOP, SMC, SVC, TBNZ or TBZ instruction.
For the B, B.cond, BL, BRK, CBNZ, CBZ, HVC, ISB, NOP, SMC, SVC, TBNZ and TBZ instructions, the architecture guarantees that after modification of the instruction, behavior is consistent with execution of either:
• The instruction originally fetched.
• A fetch of the modified instruction.
For all other instructions, to avoid UNPREDICTABLE or CONSTRAINED UNPREDICTABLE behavior, instruction modifications must be explicitly synchronized before they are executed.

So why CMODX of these instructions is safe? What problem could happen with other instructions?
I understand that storing a 32-bit instruction word on ARM32/ARM64 is atomic. And the front-end usually fetches instructions with a 16/32/64 bytes window. So how does the pipeline observe an inconsistent instruction (neither old nor new)?

https://community.arm.com/support-forums/f/architectures-and-processors-forum/6328/why-some-instructions-are-not-required-to-be-explicitly-synchronized
Please provide a reference to the particular platform you are talking about.  This is NOT for all ARM CPUs.  The conditions you discuss are for very particular ARM models.  What research have you done?  For what CPU families do your statements apply?  These are basic efforts that should be shown before asking questions. how-to-ask.

This might be implementation specific but the requirement is defined by  arm Architecture spec. I will add more info about it.

"the requirement is defined by arm Architecture spec"; I am pretty sure this is ARMv8 specific and is not something in earlier ARM specifications.  Do you understand that point or you are asserting this if true for ARMv4, etc?

@artlessnoise It starts from ARMv7 spec. My question is why the synchronization is required, not how to deal with this rule when programming. I have updated the description.
